# Store files directly into database or into project path

Tags: java, file-upload

I want to know what is the best way to store uploaded file.

Is there any performance related issues and benefits between storing in these two ways: (storing in DB and storing in project path)

Which kind of risks can be occurred in each way when retrieving files?

Answer (score 0):

If volume of files (the overall storage that you need) is not high better to use DB. But if there are a lot of large files that need to be uploaded, better to use filesystem.

In case of DB, pros:

- All data is in one place so you can easily read all you need from a single place.
- DB level permissions can be applied to stored files too.
- You can parse/process file contents using DB level procedures.
- You can use full-text search of the DB system.
- Backup/resore of data will be easier because everything is in DB.

cons:

- In case of larger volume of data, storage/retrieval of data will take a lot of time.

For filesystem, pros:

- You can handle larger storages.

Cons:

- Opposite of all cons of storing data in the database, especially the backup/restore process will be much more difficult and complex.